# FastAPI - CORS and slowapi

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

I'm currently deploying a webapp with the backend using fastapi/heroku and the frontend react/netlify. Originally I had a CORS (CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin') issue that was resolved using CORSMiddleware.

In decided to look into rate limiting for my app and through research found slowapi to be the most recommended. The issue however is when implementing slowapi through their documentation (https://slowapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I'm back to receiving the CORS errors again.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue and had a workaround? Or is there a better way overall to rate limit my app.

Sample code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address)
origins = [example_origin]

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=origins)
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)

@app.get("/home")
@limiter.limit("5/minute")
def homepage(request: Request):
    return {"test": "words"}
```

Comment: What at the exact error messages that the browse is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it to you, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools to check it. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker The exact error message in the console is "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at <<website url>>. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

Answer (score 1):

Update: The issue was resolved by including importing "Request", something which isn't noted in the slowapi docs, and request: Request in the end point (which is included in the docs)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

@app.get("/home")
def homepage(request: Request):
    return {"test": "words"}
```